# Get certain properties from large json object

Tags: angularjs, json, object

Im receiving a huge json object, I need to take only two properties from it.

The json comes like this

```
"{\r\n\"d\" : [\r\n{\r\n\"__metadata\": {\r\n\"uri\": \"http:\/\/xx.xx.xx\/AciApi.svc\/Port_Domestic(1191)\", \"type\": \"ACIModel.Port_Domestic\"\r\n}, \"PortID\": 1191, \"PortName\": \"PORTLAND\"\r\n}, {\r\n\"__metadata\": {\r\n\"uri\": \"http:\/\/xx.xx.xx\/AciApi.svc\/Port_Domestic(1192)\", \"type\": \"ACIModel.Port_Domestic\"\r\n}, \"PortID\": 1192, \"PortName\": \"BANGOR\"\r\n}, {\r\n\"__metadata\": {\r\n\"uri\": \"http:\/\/xx.xx.xx\/AciApi.svc\/Port_Domestic(1193)\", \"type\": \"ACIModel.Port_Domestic\"\r\n}, \"PortID\": 1193, \"PortName\": \"LUBEC\"\r\n}, {\r\n\"__metadata\": {\r\n\"uri\":....
```

I need only the PortName and the PortID to be like this

```
0:{portCode:"",portName:""},
1:{portCode:"",portName:""},
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var jsonString = "{\r\n\"d\" : [\r\n{\r\n\"__metadata\": {\r\n\"uri\": \"http:\/\/xx.xx.xx\/AciApi.svc\/Port_Domestic(1191)\", \"type\": \"ACIModel.Port_Domestic\"\r\n}, \"PortID\": 1191, \"PortName\": \"PORTLAND\"\r\n}, {\r\n\"__metadata\": {\r\n\"uri\": \"http:\/\/xx.xx.xx\/AciApi.svc\/Port_Domestic(1192)\", \"type\": \"ACIModel.Port_Domestic\"\r\n}, \"PortID\": 1192, \"PortName\": \"BANGOR\"\r\n}, {\r\n\"__metadata\": {\r\n\"uri\": \"http:\/\/xx.xx.xx\/AciApi.svc\/Port_Domestic(1193)\", \"type\": \"ACIModel.Port_Domestic\"\r\n}, \"PortID\": 1193, \"PortName\": \"LUBEC\"\r\n}]}"

var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString).d;

var arrayOfObjectsWithOnlyThose2Properties = jsonArray.map(function(item){ 
   return {
     "portCode": item.PortCode,
     "portName": item.PortName
   }
});
    
console.log(arrayOfObjectsWithOnlyThose2Properties);
```

Comment: This is getting me this error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 11576
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)  do you know why?

Comment: At this point we'd have to see your full json string, the one in the post isn't that long.

Comment: the complete json are here in script.js [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/99tdpV/)  @Dan_D

Comment: Looks like your string is not formatted properly in javascript you can use single or double quotes to identify a string.  In your case, double, but INT'L is being escaped as `INT\\'L` which is causing the invalid string. If you have no control over the output you will have to replace all instances of `\\'` with `'`

Comment: how do you do that? @dan-d